# Can you help me with/about/on that?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If they're correct, what's difference between these sentences?

- Can you help me with that?
- Can you help me on that?
- Can you help me about that?

e.g.: I'm trying to find the lyrics of a song and I ask someone if they could help. Which one should I use?

Comment: They are all correct, though the last seems a bit odd. It depends what the context is to determine which preposition to use. If you could write a few examples for what you are looking for it would help, otherwise this is a very broad question.

Comment: Now you've edited the post, I'd suggest something like *can you help me finding it?*

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for the lyrics of a song.

> Can you help me **with** *(finding)* that?
>
> *Can you help me find that?*
>   *Can you help me look* ***for*** *that*?
>   *Could you give me some help* ***on*** *that subject*?

You are having trouble **with** *something* and would like help in dealing **with** *it*

Answer (score 0):

> Can you help me with that?

*X with Y* has a lot of meanings.  One meaning is "uses Y in doing/achieving/obtaining X".

So you can think of this as meaning "Can you help me to use/do/get that?"

> Can you help me on that?

*X on Y* has a lot of meanings.  One meaning is to say Y is a topic, when X is a conversation or other event where information is exchanged, such as a class, book, etc.

So you can think of this as meaning "Can you give me any help regarding the topic of Y?"

> Can you help me about that?

*X about Y* has a few meanings.  One meaning is that Y is something to understand or learn.  Another meaning is that you are near Y such that you can be considered exposed to it.

However, *about* kinda-sorta has an underlying "need" to work like a location (and it also has a less common meaning that's related to location as well).  Therefore, verbs with *about* generally tend to be "directed" with *to*.

When the meaning is similar to *on Y* above, the concept is that you are being "exposed" to the knowledge.

*Help* is not a verb that can take a complement that's a location, so *help me about X* is weird.  But there's other verbs that work fine.

> I'm walking about the rose garden. (you're physically in the rose garden)

> Show me about the roses. (can mean take me through a rose garden or introduce me about your rose collection)

> Can you talk to me about that?